# How to get Resource name?

Tags: android, random, arraylist

How to get image name and display it in a textbox?
I used arraylist that generates random images.

```
String ImageName = getResources().getResourceName((Integer)list.get(position));
```

The output I get from this code is R.drawable.image1. How to get the image name image1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(image[position]);
```

Comment: thanks it works!I just changed something                        String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(list.get(position));

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string.substring(string.lastIndexOf("."),string.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String name = "image1";
int imgId = getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + name, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Comment: I believe it's not "drawable/" + name, just name